# How to render efficiently few hundreds of angular highcharts in the browser without crashing?

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts, scroll

I have an application that needs to render hundreds of highchart scatter plots in a single page in rows of 3 charts. The number can range from 100+ to even 2000+. 
The calculations and creation of these charts are pretty fast, but the bottleneck is really in the rendering of them into the page itself. It usually takes more than a minute up to 5 minutes, which is really slow and inefficient.

What are some suggestions out there to speed things up? 
I have tried to implement Cdk Virtual Scroller but it was really buggy for my experience. The order of the charts will be shuffled whenever you scroll up and down. And sometimes the charts will disappear entirely and leave a blank chart in its place.

code snippet:

```
 <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="500" class="viewport" style="width: 2000px; height: 1100px;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col" *cdkVirtualFor="let nth_chart of chartObjects; index as i">
        <div class="clearfix" *ngIf="i % 3 == 0"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div style="width: auto; height: auto;" [chart]="nth_chart"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

Would pagination solve the problem? I am thinking pagination will run into the same issue because it has to render to charts to each page first before returning the entire 'pagination' div?

Comment: Unfortunately, Highcharts Angular wrapper doesn't offer any option to menage multiple charts. What can I do is suggest how to get the best performance in Highcharts: https://highcharts.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/44001027377

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting [Change detection strategy](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy) to `OnPush`. It's well explained [here](https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4)

Another way could be [web workers](https://angular.io/guide/web-worker). Using web workers you can run code on "background" thread and free your main thread to be able to update the user interface.

> You can add a web worker anywhere in your application. For example, to add a 
>   web worker to the root component, src/app/app.component.ts, run the following 
>   command.
>
> `ng generate web-worker app`
>
> Source: https://angular.io/guide/web-worker